# 100% element in a width-fixed container with position property?

Tags: css

### [My issue on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ibUyAyE/1/)

---

I  have a `div` container with text.

```
<div id="container">
      Some text with normal content flow...
      <div id="wholescreen">Some 100% text</div>
      Some text again, without #wholescreen above the content.
      #wholescreen must respect the content flow.
 </div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
   width: 200px; 
   margin: auto;
}
```

Inside, i want a a 100% element.

```
#wholescreen {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%
}
```

This works. **But it was above the text.** So, I tried `position: relative`:

```
#wholescreen {
   position: relative;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%
}
```

Now is not over the element, but it is not 100% too.

What I do? I want **[this result](http://sketchtoy.com/58310528)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `#wholescreen` has a fixed `height`, add a `margin-top` in the element directly after it:

```css
#wholescreen + * {
  margin-top: /* value */;
}
```

**This will not affect other elements**. Like I said, only the element after `#wholescreen`.

» **[Example on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/EbeceCa/1/)**

---

**If you *can* change HTML...**

Why do not you try this?

```
<div class="container">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
<div id="wholescreen">100%</div>
<div class="container">Consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
```

The difference is that an element will not be child of another. :P

» **[Example on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/oRoLiWA/1)**

Comment: So clever! Why didnt I think of that? Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

give position relative to the parent of container
and give position absolute to #wholescreen
but if you change css property position for any #wholescreen parent you might break this effect

```
body{
    position:relative
}
#wholescreen {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   top: 50px; // give it a top value
}
```

in case you want #wholescreen to attach to the window and not move when scrolling, use

```
#wholescreen{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

check fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/AdVL8/6/

**New EDIT**

I gave it a better look and I've realised that you might not want to have an element hiding the text, so I think this is the effect that you want:

```
body{
    /* remove position: relative; */
}
#wholescreen{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    left: 50%; /* the property that will help us find the center of the screen */
    width: 2000px; /* a width wider than any screen */
    margin-left: -1000px; /* centers the element (must be 50% of the width) */
}
```

Comment: There is a problem with content flow: http://jsfiddle.net/AdVL8/1/, with `position: relative` everything is fine: http://jsfiddle.net/AdVL8/2/. #wholescreen is above #container, if you see.

Comment: no problem, just remove the height: 100px, because it was used for displaying a certain height so you could see the colored elements.

Comment: I know that. But #wholescreen is above the content: http://jsfiddle.net/AdVL8/3/. Is not respecting the content, like `position: relative` does: http://jsfiddle.net/AdVL8/4/

Comment: give it a top value and it will behave as you want, check my update

Comment: oh I think I understand now what you want, you want a natural vertical spacing between the content and the #wholescreen div, so that no content gets hidden, correct? check my next edit

Comment: Thanks I like your solution But the width should not be fixed =S